# DB time always showing as zero in Rails development log timings

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've noticed that the Rails log correctly displays the time taken to execute an action in the logs, and that the **View:** part of that is also rendered correctly.  However, the **DB:** value is always zero:

```
Aug 11 13:00:22 [2326] INFO: Completed in 2072ms (View: 94, DB: 0) | 200 OK
```

In fact, all my DB timings are being logged as zero.  I'm logging at DEBUG level, in development mode, running Rails 2.3.2.

Apologies in advance if the answer is blatantly obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the time zone in your environment.rb?

```
config.active_record.default_timezone = 'UTC'
config.time_zone = 'UTC'
```

Comment: I have set `config.active_record.default_timezone = :utc` and also `ENV['TZ'] = 'UTC'`